# Why can I access a private instance variable without a getter method?

Tags: java

I have two objects from the same class, calling it 'first' and 'second'. I have a method that takes in an object, so I use the 'first' object, call that method, pass in the 'second' object into that method.

Inside that method, why can I access the private instance variable of the 'second' object? Am I making any sense?

```
// Day.java, basic example of my question
public class Day{

  private int stuff = 1;

  public Day(int stuff){
   this.stuff = stuff;

  }

  public int m(Day d){ // This method takes in an object as a parameter
   int add = 0;
   add = this.day + d.day; // why can you do this? isn't "day" private?
   return add;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Access Modifiers]

Source https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/access-modifiers-java/
You are accessing it from the same class
**Check this Table Out..**

Comment: Okay that chart makes sense! I see where I'm off, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're still accessing your variable from within the same class it belongs to.

`private` variables are not visible from outside the class: but they are fully visible from within the class to which they belong.

If you tried to instantiate your class inside a different class, you'd have to use a getter to gain access.